# HTML/Javascript Validating inputs and continuing to next page

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to html/js so bear with me. I'm trying to create an html form that only accepts inputs in certain types. I can get it to work by itself but when I try to add a "continue" button, to take it to the next page, it basically disregards all the stipulations and just automatically goes to the next page. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<html>
<body>

<head>
<h1>
Validation Form
</h1>
</head>



<form name="myform"
method="post">

First Name: <input id="fname" type = "text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required 
name = "Fname">
<br> <br>
Last Name: <input id="lname" type = "text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required 
name = "Lname">


<br> <br>



Gender

<select>
<option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
</select>

<br> <br>

State

<select>
<option value="california">California</option>
<option value="florida">Florida</option>
<option value="newyork">New York</option>
<option value="texas">Texas</option>
<option value="hawaii">Hawaii</option>
<option value="washington">Washington</option>
<option value="colorado">Colorado</option>
<option value="virginia">Virginia</option>
<option value="iowa">Iowa</option>
<option value="arizona">Arizona</option>
</select>

<br> <br>



</form>
<form action="validation2.html">
<input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why have you used 2nd form? Submit button can be part of 1st form itself.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Can't believe I din't think of that, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

I see you got the main issue there. Since you are new, I will give you a couple quick bonus tips. I hope you are having fun. In a couple months if you keep practicing, you will be quite proficient.

Here is your code and I will tell you what I changed:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cool Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Validation Form</h1>

        <form name="myform" method="POST" action="validation2.html">

            First Name:
            <input id="fname" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required name="Fname">
            <br><br>

            Last Name:
            <input id="lname" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required name="Lname">
            <br><br>

            Gender
            <select>
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>

            State
            <select>
                <option value="california">California</option>
                <option value="florida">Florida</option>
                <option value="newyork">New York</option>
                <option value="texas">Texas</option>
                <option value="hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="washington">Washington</option>
                <option value="colorado">Colorado</option>
                <option value="virginia">Virginia</option>
                <option value="iowa">Iowa</option>
                <option value="arizona">Arizona</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

1. Notice how I changed the `<body>` to start after the `</head>`. It must be this way. The head comes first, and then the body, all inside the html tags.
2. I added a title tag so you can have a title in your browser tab.
3. I improved the readability of the code by showing you an example how the parent/child associations work, and put related items with each other. It is subjective, so you are absolutely free to make it look how you want, but this is what more experienced people will do.
4. Notice how `method="POST"` is capitalized now. Usually, we capitalize POST and GET methods, but its not required.
5. I made your Submit Button as a button. Notice the type="submit" and how it's inside the form. It is a child element in its parent form. People will call this more "semantic", which means it is more precise to its actual meaning, and it has some bearing on when computers read your code. It helps them and people with disabilities understand what your code means.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your submit input is submitting the second form not the first form that has the input fields with restrictions.

Modify the first form opening tag to:

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="validation2.html">
```

Delete the first form's closing tag and the second form's opening tag so you have:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

That way, you end up with **one** form that has the fields, the selects, and the submit input.